# How to avoid multiple instances of view controller when presenting

Tags: ios, swift3

I have view controller called JobdetailsViewcontroller. I want only instance to be created for that controller. I mean if view controller is already presented want to dismiss the previous and present new one again.
Here is my use case. I have method "ShowJobdetails" which will call so many places in my app.

```
func ShowJobdetails(_ attributes: NSDictionary)
{
   /// Cheking if it's already presented 
    if let jobdetais = self.Jobdetails
    {
        jobdetais.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

            self.PresentJobdetails(attributes)

        })
    }
    else{
        self.PresentJobdetails(attributes)
    }

}

 func PresentJobdetails(_ attributes: NSDictionary)
 {
    /// initialing view controller and presenting it.
    AppManager.topViewController()?.present(Jobdetails, animated: true, completion: {

        self.Jobdetails = Jobdetails /// here I'm saving instance of view controller. 

  })
```

But if call "ShowJobdetails"  2 times at same time, My view controller is presenting 2 times one over the other.

How to avoid this scenario?

Thank you

Comment: By "call ShowJobdetails 2 times at same time" you mean you call PresentJobdetails(...) twice in a single function?

Answer (score 1):

you could store your jobdetailsviewcontroller locally and do something like this:

```
lazy var jobDetailsViewController: JobDetailsViewController = {
    return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JobDetailsViewController") as! JobDetailsViewController
}()

@IBAction func presentJobDetails() {
    if let presentedViewController = presentedViewController, presentedViewController == jobDetailsViewController {
        // already presented
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.presentJobDetails()
        })
        return
    }

    // prepare your jobdetailsviewcontroller here
    present(jobDetailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue that stands out to me is that you are calling .dismiss() on jobDetails, which is the presented view controller. But, dismiss() needs to be called on the presenting view controller.

Comment: This is not an issue. Is not a good practice, but it is allowed. From the documentation: "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal."

Answer (score 0):

I wander where do you init your `self.Jobdetails` and  it always exists a `Jobdetails`!

So the judge in the `let if jobdetais = self.Jobdetails` may never work

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the last presented view controller is JobDetailsViewController and dismiss it in such case:

```
func showJobDetails(_ attributes: NSDictionary) {
    let presenter = AppManager.topViewController()

    let jobDetailsViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JobDetailsViewController") as! JobDetailsViewController

    // Configure jobDetailsViewController here, e.g.
    //jobDetailsViewController.attributes = attributes

    if presenter?.presentedViewController?.isKind(of: JobDetailsViewController.self) == .some(true) {
        presenter?.dismiss(animated: true) {
            presenter?.present(jobDetailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        presenter?.present(jobDetailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it works. In my case I have used `view.window?.rootViewController` as a presenter.

**Edit:** An alternative way how to avoid multiple instances of view controller would be to not dismiss the view controller, just change it's content. But I don't know if that is ok in you use case.

Also note that in Swift we write variable and function names with lowercase starting letters. And if you write a pure Swift application I would use `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`... for example `[String: String]` or `[String: Any]`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will try this way, I think the presented view controller is assigned after view did load. So what will happen before view did load called if i present again

Comment: This is related to what I am asking in the comment below your question. You cannot present a view controller while another view controller is being presented (with animation). So the solution is to not present before the previous view controller is fully presented. Otherwise you might also get UIKit warnings and/or wrong behaviour.

Comment: Looking at your code, if you call `ShowJobdetails` twice in a row, than your original code will not work because you are setting `self.Jobdetails = Jobdetails` too late. Move it from the completion handler to the beginning of the `PresentJobdetails` method. Because completion handler is also called after `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: If i set the self.Jobdetails = Jobdetails before, Some times my view controller is not presented but I'm trying to dismiss which is not working

Comment: Your problem really is that you are messing up the presentations. You cannot present while other presentation is in progress. Normally this is not a problem, because you present on some user action (button is pressed) and while the presentation is in progress, user can not press the button again. Here the problem is "Some times my view controller is not presented". Why it is not? Check your console if you don't see any UIKit warnings.